# Is there a way to specify streaming video resolution/canvas size in html5/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, video

Is there a way to specify/modify video resolution/canvas size in html5/Javascript?

Tried to set video.videoHeight and video.videoWidth, but these seem to be not modifiable.

This sets up the video camera window:

```
  $("#videoControl").show();  
  video = document.createElement("video");  
  canvasElement = $("#qrCanvas")[0];  
  canvas = canvasElement.getContext("2d");  
  window.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { facingMode: "environment" } }).then(function (stream) {  
 video.srcObject = stream;  
 video.setAttribute("playsinline", true); // required to tell iOS safari we don't want fullscreenvideo.play();  
 requestAnimationFrame(tick);  
 }
```

I added:

```
  video.setAttribute("width",'320');  
  video.setAttribute("height",'240');
```

Got: "640 x 480" via:
  window.alert(v`enter code here`ideo.videoWidth  + " x " + video.videoHeight);

grep did not find in the programs 640 x 480 nor are there other references to object video.

Comment: Show us your relevant code.  These attributes are supposed to be settable.

Comment: Am trying to modify a program which has this fragment:

    canvasElement.height = video.videoHeight;
    canvasElement.width  = video.videoWidth;
    canvas.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);      The video was 640x480. Prefixing with video.style.width = 240; video.style.height = 320; had no effect

Comment: Does your code look substantially like this?  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_height.asp

Comment: There is no <video> tag (did grep search). It is a big set of programs and I have no idea how the video camera widow is created.

Comment: That's the first thing you need to figure out.  How are you possibly going to solve this problem if you don't even know where it is?

Comment: Hi Robert. After more research found how the video camera window is created. Please see the updated question. Thank you.

Comment: Found a workaround using an html table with two columns. Put the video window in left column and assigned it 20% of table size. 80% went to an iframe which I needed.,  As a result te camera's window adaptively "shrunk:"